# Elastic Beanstalk 502 error when deploying war file to Tomcat

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, war, tomcat8

I've deployed a Shopizer war file to a Tomcat Elastic Beanstalk instance. I've configured a mySQL database and as far as I can tell everything should be correct. the problem is that when I try to access the URL I get a 502 error. I'm aware Elastic Beanstalk times out after 60s so I increased my timeout limit but still get the problem.

I've noticed this in my Catalina.out log. I know its only a warning but could it possibly point to my issue?

> 2018-05-02 06:02:51.220  WARN 3233 --- [-AdminTaskTimer] c.m.v.a.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner     : com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@4446a77 -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Complete Status: 
>       Managed Threads: 3
>       Active Threads: 3
>       Active Tasks: 
>           com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@55aa1343
>               on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1br9tjp9v8puiagh4cnwb|550ee827]-HelperThread-#2
>           com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@326b931e
>               on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1br9tjp9v8puiagh4cnwb|550ee827]-HelperThread-#0
>           com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@7fc7b7d9
>               on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1br9tjp9v8puiagh4cnwb|550ee827]-HelperThread-#1
>       Pending Tasks: 
>           com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@591e9ef6
>   Pool thread stack traces:
>       Thread[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1br9tjp9v8puiagh4cnwb|550ee827]-HelperThread-#2,5,main]
>           java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
>           java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>           java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>           java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>           java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>           java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>           com.mysql.cj.core.io.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:202)
>           com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaSocketConnection.connect(MysqlaSocketConnection.java:57)
>           com.mysql.cj.mysqla.MysqlaSession.connect(MysqlaSession.java:122)
>           com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:1619)
>           com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:1601)
>           com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:633)
>           com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:347)
>           com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:219)
>           com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:175)
>           com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:220)
>           com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:206)
>           com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:203)
>           com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138)
>           com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125)
>           com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
>           com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870)
>           com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
>       Thread[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1br9tjp9v8puiagh4cnwb|550ee827]-HelperThread-#0,5,main]
>           java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
>           java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>           java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>           java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>           java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>           java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>           com.mysql.cj.core.io.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:202)
>           com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaSocketConnection.connect(MysqlaSocketConnection.java:57)
>           com.mysql.cj.mysqla.MysqlaSession.connect(MysqlaSession.java:122)
>           com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:1619)
>           com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:1601)
>           com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:633)
>           com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:347)
>           com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:219)
>           com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:175)
>           com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:220)
>           com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:206)
>           com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:203)
>           com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138)
>           com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125)
>           com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
>           com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870)
>           com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
>       Thread[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1br9tjp9v8puiagh4cnwb|550ee827]-HelperThread-#1,5,main]
>           java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
>           java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>           java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>           java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>           java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>           java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>           com.mysql.cj.core.io.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:202)
>           com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaSocketConnection.connect(MysqlaSocketConnection.java:57)
>           com.mysql.cj.mysqla.MysqlaSession.connect(MysqlaSession.java:122)
>           com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:1619)
>           com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:1601)
>           com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:633)
>           com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:347)
>           com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:219)
>           com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:175)
>           com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:220)
>           com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:206)
>           com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:203)
>           com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138)
>           com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125)
>           com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
>           com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870)
>           com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
>
> 2018-05-02 06:03:51.222  WARN 3233 --- [-AdminTaskTimer] c.m.v.a.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner     : Task com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@55aa1343 (in deadlocked PoolThread) failed to complete in maximum time 60000ms. Trying interrupt().
>   2018-05-02 06:03:51.222  WARN 3233 --- [-AdminTaskTimer] c.m.v.a.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner     : Task com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@326b931e (in deadlocked PoolThread) failed to complete in maximum time 60000ms. Trying interrupt().
>   2018-05-02 06:03:51.222  WARN 3233 --- [-AdminTaskTimer] c.m.v.a.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner     : Task com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@7fc7b7d9 (in deadlocked PoolThread) failed to complete in maximum time 60000ms. Trying interrupt().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I messed about with quite a few steps and haven't looked through what helped and what didn't. If I get a chance to go through that and give more specific help I will but for now, heres what I did.

- In `sm-shop/src/main/resources/application.properties` add:

  `server.port = 5000`
- Start with creating a database. You'll need the details for the database.properties file. I created a mySQL Aurora DB.
- Add the database properties to `sm-shop/src/main/resources/database.properties`.
- In AWS, create Elastic Beanstalk application and environment. I went with Tomcat so had to build a war file, which I deployed to the environment.
- In Configuration > Software set the following:

  `Initial JVM heap size (Xms) = 1024m
    Max JVM heap size (Xmx) = 1024m
    XX:MaxPermSize = 256m`
- Add the following Environment Properties:

  `HIBERNATE_DIALECT = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    JDBC_CONNECTION_STRING = jdbc:mysql://mydb.ptmjbhdur9pw.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/SALESMANAGER?user=username&password=password&autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&&driverClass=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    SERVER_PORT = 5000`
- In Configuration > Modify instances:

  `Instance type = (at least)m1.small`
    EC2 security groups - I ticked the database security group here.
- In Configuration > Modify capacity:
    Environment type = Load balanced
- In Configuration > Load balancer add the following listener:

  `Port = 8080
    Protocol = HTTP
    Instance Port = 8080
    Instance Protocol = HTTP`

When all that was done and I started the application without any apparent AWS issues, the application wouldn't load so I checked the Catalina log. It showed the same error as in [https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/shopizer/ru%7Csort:date/shopizer/hQjqp_5UswI/goVKf5BTCQAJ](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/shopizer/ru%7Csort:date/shopizer/hQjqp_5UswI/goVKf5BTCQAJ/) so I made that change. The application now loads.

I hope that saves somebody some time(and grief).